# Login details not accepted after fresh install

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I am fresh to alfresco, I've installed alfresco on CentOS but unable to login.

Am getting this errors.

both are not able to login. i.e. share & alfresco [image]

[image]

I don't no what is the issue. Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The reason you can't log into Share is that the repository (alfresco.war) webapp hasn't started. Do you have anything helpful in the logs about why it couldn't start?

Comment: "ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] Context initialization failed" this was the error found in logs

Comment: post the full log from repository startup

Answer (score 0):

Please start the tomcat where the alfresco is installed and then try to login.

Comment: Issue sorted out, i made some corrections in alfresco-global.properties file.